# Yii framework, getting related image columns by specific language

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I've hit a small-ish problem while working with Yii framework.
To explain the situation:
I have to create a *sales-promotion* slider of sorts. Each *promotion* consists of a **url** to more information about the promotion and an **image url**. Each promotion has several localized versions of it's image. For this purpose I've created 2 database tables -
First is the promotions table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `promotions` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `image` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,  
  `destination` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `image` (`image`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

and second is the promotion images table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `promoImages` (  
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `language` varchar(2) NOT NULL,  
  `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `language` (`language`),  
  KEY `mhm` (`pid`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

The idea with such database structure is that in each *promotions* table row in the field **image** it contains an identifier for the appropriate image, then in table *promoImages* the related column **pid** contains the unique promotion identifier. Each promotion can be localized in several undefined languages, so for each image that is related to a single promotion there can be several rows in *promoImages*, an example of this:

```
INSERT INTO `promoImages` (`id`, `pid`, `language`, `url`) VALUES  
(1, 1, 'lv', '/path/to/image1_lv.png'),  
(2, 2, 'lv', '/path/to/image2_lv.png'),  
(3, 3, 'lv', '/path/to/image3_lv.png'),  
(4, 1, 'en', '/path/to/image1_en.png'),  
(5, 2, 'en', '/path/to/image2_en.png'),  
(6, 3, 'en', '/path/to/image3_en.png'),  
(7, 1, 'ru', '/path/to/image1_ru.png'),  
(8, 2, 'ru', '/path/to/image2_ru.png'),  
(9, 3, 'ru', '/path/to/image3_ru.png');
```

Now with that structure in mind I also created a foreign key in table *promotions* which generated along with Yii frameworks "Gii" tool created models with such relations:
Table *promotions* model relation

```
'promoImages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PromoImages', 'pid'),
```

and table *promoImages* model relation

```
'p' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Promotions', 'pid'),
```

And as far as I know, the relation is correct, single *promotion* can have multiple *promoImages* table rows and any *promoImages* row can only belong to single *promotion*, as I correct to believe this is true?

I hope I've explained the situation as thoroughly as possible, now onto the issue itself.
As I mentioned at top, from all that I really only need to retrieve 2 values, 1 from each table: **destination** from *promotions* and **url** from *promoImages* but as I'm selecting these values I need to keep in mind only selecting those promotions whose **status** is "1" meaning that the promotion is active. Also when selecting the promotion image I need to select the row from table *promoImages* which corresponds to both the promotions **image** column aswell as current chosen application language(Yii::app()->language).

So far the code I have is as follows:
The promotion widget controller

```
public function run() {
    $l = Yii::app()->language;
    $promos = Promotions::model()->with('promoImages')->findAll('status=:status AND promoImages.language=:language', array(
        ':status' => 1,
        ':language' => $l
    ));

    $this->render('promo', array('promotions' => $promos));
}
```

the promotion widget view

```
foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
    // $image = $promotion->promoImages->url;
    $dest = $promotion->destination;
    echo "<div class='promo_hold'>";
        echo "<a href='$dest'><img src='$image'></a>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

This gives me the 3 div's I need for the 3 active promotions but with empty images, if I uncomment the $image definition I get the **Trying to get property of non-object** error and this is basically where I'm stuck, I've looked at Yii's class reference but so far it hasn't gotten me any help.

If I'm missing any required information please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks beforehand!

P.S. I hope my wall of text doesn't actually scare away people who might have an answer :O

Comment: Does `$promotion->getAttribute('destination')` work? What's the output of `var_dump`ing `$promotions` - an array of models or null?

Comment: Please active the sql log and detect what SQL is computed for this cause, that will help you to see what is queried and what you have access to. And since you are using with, and relations you must add together() to be resolved by 1 query.

Comment: @bcmfcf using `getAttribute('destination')` works, gives me the proper destination while `$promotion->getAttribute('url');` gives me `null`. var_dump($promotions) returns an array of ActiveRecord objects.  
@pentium10 I'm not sure how I can enable SQL Log? Usually I only see the sql error when there's a problem with it, it's not the case this time as when I `var_dump/print_r $promotions` I can find the information I need in the mess of things it produces, I just need to figure out how to address the correct field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer to my question myself so I'll add it as an answer here in-case someone else has a problem like this.
While trying all kinds of variations to get the field I need I noticed that `$promotion->promoImages` is actually an *array* containing single element, the *object* that contains all the information relating to selected promotion and language.

So I came to such a solution for this problem, in widgets *foreach* loop I simply set:

```
$image = $promotion->promoImages[0]->url;
```

And that is showing me the correct, language selected image address.